# Parameterize the existence of solutions for a given linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $b_1,\dots, b_n$ be a given set of positive constants. Let $c_1$ and $c_2$ be two positive variables we are interested in. Consider the system of equations in the non-negative variables $x_i$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}c_1 \\ c_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & \dots & 1 \\ 0 & b_1 & \dots & b_n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_o \\ x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{bmatrix}~~,~~x_i \geq 0 ~\forall i
\end{align}
What are conditions on $c_1,c_2$ such that the above linear system always has a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $x_1$ so that $x_1 b_1 = c_2$, which you can always do by the positivity of $b$ and $c$. Then make $x_{n \geq 2} =0$, and take $x_0 = c_1 - x_1$. This is not guaranteed to give you positive solution, but in general you want to make the $x_1$ have the smallest possible sum, while keeping the weight sum with the $b_i$ equal to $c_2$. Clearly, the best way to do that is the just make all of the $c_2$ come from the largest corresponding of the $b_i$. So the key condition is that $$ \frac{c_2}{b_m} \leq c_1 $$ where $b_m$ is the maximum of the $b_i$.